# Cannot reboot after failing to install kubuntu

Tags: linux, boot, operating-systems, kubuntu

I was trying to install Kubuntu on my laptop (I am using Acer laptop). After booting to the USB contains the setup of Kubuntu, I decided to try Ubuntu first. When finished trying, I pressed restart in Kubuntu live session, after a while, my laptop showed this on the screen. I get this image on internet, but the contents are the same:

[image: Screen shot]

Then I unplugged the USB and pressed enter. Now it shows this on the screen:

[image: what it is showing now on my screen]

At first, there were only 2 lines on top. After waiting for a long, I hold the power button for 3 seconds and it showed some lines that follow the first 2 lines.

Now I can't reboot or do anything. What should I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I find that when I press the power button, the keyboard backlight does not light up, the other kets still make the backlight light up. Also, only power button holding generates the "unknown key pressed..." message.

Comment: "I hold the power button and …" – For how long? Hold for several seconds.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski For around 3 seconds.

Comment: Hold for 30 seconds.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It works! Don't know why I don't even think about that. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold the power button for as long as it takes. The laptop will eventually power itself off.